# Custom Vue Input Component not Displaying Bound Value

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component

I've created a vue component to reuse thoughout my app but I'm struggling with one aspect the value being initially displayed in the input text field. It feels like there is something I'm misunderstanding about the the render cycle and how value binding works.

Here is the Vue component that I've made:

```
<template>
  <div class="my-2">
    <label for="name">{{ label }} </label>
    <input
      :id="id"
      :name="name"
      :class="{
        input: true,
        'input-error': errorMessage && errorMessage != '',
      }"
      :value="value"
      v-on:input="action"
      :type="type"
      :required="!!required"
      v-once
    />
    <p v-show="errorMessage && errorMessage != ''" class="error-message">
      {{ errorMessage }}
    </p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "BaseInput",
  props: [
    "defaultValue",
    "label",
    "type",
    "id",
    "name",
    "errorMessage",
    "required",
  ],
  computed: { 
    value() {
      console.log(this.defaultValue);
      return this.defaultValue
    },
  },
  methods: {
    action(e) {
      this.$emit("input", e.target.value);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

and I reference it in my parent component as such:

```
<base-input label="Base Input 2" id="in2" name="name" v-model="value"></base-input> {{value}}
```

when the page loads the  `{{value}}` displays value as expected, but the input does not actually display the text

Comment: You need to listen for `@input` in the parent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `defaultValue` prop to `value` as shown below. This should setup a two-way binding between your child and parent.

```
<template>
      <div class="my-2">
        <label for="name">{{ label }} </label>
        <input
          :id="id"
          :name="name"
          :class="{
            input: true,
            'input-error': errorMessage && errorMessage != '',
          }"
          :value="value"
          v-on:input="action"
          :type="type"
          :required="!!required"
          v-once
        />
        <p v-show="errorMessage && errorMessage != ''" class="error-message">
          {{ errorMessage }}
        </p>
      </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    export default {
      name: "BaseInput",
      props: [
        "value",
        "label",
        "type",
        "id",
        "name",
        "errorMessage",
        "required",
      ],
      methods: {
        action(e) {
          this.$emit("input", e.target.value);
        },
      },
    };
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate you putting the time in to help me on this

Answer (score 1):

in order to achieve a two way binding on a custom component you have to follow a special syntax on your child component. You have to pass the `value` as a prop and emit the `input` on a method. Try updating you're code like this:

```
<template>
  <div class="my-2">
    <label for="name">{{ label }} </label>
    <input
      :id="id"
      :name="name"
      :class="{
        input: true,
        'input-error': errorMessage && errorMessage != '',
      }"
      :value="value"
      v-on:input="action"
      :type="type"
      :required="!!required"
      v-once
    />
    <p v-show="errorMessage && errorMessage != ''" class="error-message">
      {{ errorMessage }}
    </p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "BaseInput",
  props: [
    "defaultValue",
    "label",
    "type",
    "id",
    "name",
    "errorMessage",
    "required",
    "value"
  ],
  methods: {
    action(e) {
      this.$emit("input", e.target.value);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

with `value` as a prop and not a computed property. More about this on the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components)